# To what math branches are these assignments related to

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have two different assignments:

## 1

Hailey was asked to hang seven paintings in a row on the wall. In how many different ways can she arrange them?
**The answer would be 7!**

## 2

Calculate the amount of possibility's with 4 digits in base 3. **The answer would be 4^3.**

to what math branches are these questions related? When do I know which question belongs to which of these math branch? I seem to be confused with why you need to use different methods to each of these assignments, when you're counting the amount of possible outcomes with both assignments.

P.S. Can someone edit the tag appropiately? I don't know what tag this topic is supposed to be.

Comment: *The answer would be $7!$.*

Comment: These questions belong to a branch of mathematics known as "Combinatorics". Combinatorics is, loosely, primarily concerned with the mathematics of counting things. See wikipedia for more detail: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics

Comment: @Awertheim Thanks for the link. Would u or anyone else know why you use different ways of calculating each of these assignments?

Comment: Scenario 1 is without replacement. If you hang painting 3, you can't hang painting 3 again later. Scenario 2 is with replacement. If you pick the digit 1, you're allowed to pick the digit 1 again later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These questions are in the domain of [Combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics), a major subfield of [Discrete Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_mathematics). Discrete mathematics is the study of mathematical objects that are fundamentally finite rather than continuous. In combinatorics specifically, we study the ways in which we can arrange or count discrete objects.

In your two exercises, you have a bunch of discrete items, and you're trying to find the number of ways they can be arranged, so these are clearly combinatorial problems.